# Does AT TIME ZONE automatically take care of DST conversion?

Tags: ssrs, timezone

I have to convert UTC dates for some reports.  We are using SQL Server 2016 and all my report queries are SPs, so I was able to do this:

```
SELECT MyDateTime AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AS 'MyLocalDateTime'
```

This returns the expected value, but I have not been able to determine if this will still work during daylight savings time.

By querying the time zone info DMV:

```
 select * from sys.time_zone_info
```

I see there is a column for 'Is DST', so I am assuming the server is tracking that.  So can I safely assume sql server will adjust the time as needed during DST?

Comment: Have you tried the same value with `'Pacific Daylight Time'`?

Comment: No, but that does not exist in my time_zone_info list.  Is it a legit zone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it accounts for it:

> `AT TIME ZONE` applies specific rules for converting input values in
>   smalldatetime, datetime and datetime2 data types, *that fall into an
>   interval that is affected by the DST change*

As per the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt612795.aspx) on the expression. The `sys.time_zone_info` column supplies information on if the zone currently is in DST, but the article above indicates that the rules take into account DST given a specific date time value.

Example:

```
/*------------------------
SELECT SYSUTCDATETIME() AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time';
------------------------*/

----------------------------------
2017-01-18 22:18:12.3789253 -05:00
```

And when we try using a date with a different DST offset:

```
/*------------------------
SELECT CAST('2017-07-18' AS DATETIME) AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time';
------------------------*/

----------------------------------
2017-07-18 00:00:00.000 -04:00
```

It assigns a different DST offset value, being aware of whether or not the date falls into DST.

Answer (score 0):

In general avoid using specific *standard* or *daylight* time zones.
So instead of `Eastern Daylight Time` or `Eastern Standard Time` use the geographical style reference like `America/New_York`.
The later will give you the proper Daylight or Standard time conversion based on the date being converted.